# Why is the first group of text not aligned with the others?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying align each group of text in the middle, while keeping the text left-aligned.

The first group of text is not aligned with the others for some reason. I'm wondering what's the best approach to fix this problem. I know I can make a hacky fix by doing something like margin-left: -2rem on the first group of text.

What would be the best approach to center each group of text in the middle while having a left text alignment?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

div {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Locations</h1>
<section>
  <div>
    <h2>Corporate</h2>
    <p>17170 Loriot Rd
      Gainesville State, PA 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Alabama</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Nashville</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Birmingham</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Texas
    </h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: so you want `corporate` section to be aligned to center as others?

Comment: Correct, I would like corporate section to be aligned as others. I'm wondering the best way to center all sections while having the text left aligned. @Manjuboyz

Comment: Actually the content is indeed center, the reason it is bit off due to the more content exist under `corporate` so if your use case is to have the left aligned then it can be done.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0):

Its actually doing its job correctly. Its finding the center perfectly. it just so happens that the first one has a longer paragraph than the rest, so it adjusts accordingly.
If you gave the others the same baton rouge address, they will all fall in line.

add a big div around them and text-align: left;

```
<h1>Locations</h1>
<section>
  <div>
    <div>
    <h2>Corporate</h2>
    <p>17170 Loriot Rd
      Gainesville State, PA 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Alabama</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Nashville</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Birmingham</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Texas
    </h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
      
  </div></div>
</section>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

div {
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

*edit - added code

Answer (score 0):

For blocks, you must specify the same width, then they are automatically aligned

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section > div {
  width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

div {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Locations</h1>
<section>
  <div>
    <h2>Corporate</h2>
    <p>17170 Loriot Rd
      Gainesville State, PA 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Alabama</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Nashville</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Birmingham</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Texas
    </h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a fixed width on the div

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section div {
 width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

div {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Locations</h1>
<section>
  <div>
    <h2>Corporate</h2>
    <p>17170 Perkins Rd
      Baton Rouge, LA 70810</p>
    <span>(225) 281-4202</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Alabama</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Nashville</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Birmingham</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Texas
    </h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the width to the `div` tag since you need it for center use `%` than `px`:

Play around with [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/dbmypv20/8/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section>div{
width:50%;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

div {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Locations</h1>
<section>
  <div>
    <h2>Corporate</h2>
    <p>17170 Perkins Rd
      Baton Rouge, LA 70810 , LA 70810</p>
    <span>(225) 281-4202</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Alabama</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Nashville</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Birmingham</h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Texas
    </h2>
    <p>9999 Street Name
      City, State 99999</p>
    <span>(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it up a bit to have it fully on flexbox and also the divs need to have the same width if you don't want any being wider.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```